# Show multiple choices to admin in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I wanted to show multiple choices to admin so that at one time he can select more then one from these choices. I can do this using check boxes fields.I have tried this but instead of showing check boxes it shows me drop down list of choices.

Here is my code.

**models.py**

```
class segmentation_Rules(models.Model):
        Segmentation_Rules_CHOICES = (
                        (1, 'At least one order'),
                        (2, 'Have reward points'),
                        )
        Rules       =models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True,verbose_name="Select rules for customer segmentation",choices=Segmentation_Rules_CHOICES)
```

**forms.py**

```
class Segmentation_Form(ModelForm):
        Rules = forms.MultipleChoiceField( widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
```

**admin.py**

```
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = Segmentation_Form
```

So please show me some way so that admin can select multiple fields from choices.

**EDIT:**

And if I remove the choices from models and define them into forms then there is just a text field shown to admin with no choices.

```
Segmentation_Rules_CHOICES = (
            (1, 'At least one order'),
            (2, 'Have reward points'),
            )

class Segmentation_Form(ModelForm):
        Rules = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=Segmentation_Rules_CHOICES, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())

        class Meta:
            model=segmentation_Rules
```

Comment: Use power of: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the `choices` argument from the model field definition in **models.py** and add `choices` field to the `Rules` form field in **forms.py**. Like so:

**models.py**

```
class segmentation_Rules(models.Model):
    Segmentation_Rules_CHOICES = (
        (1, 'At least one order'),
        (2, 'Have reward points'),
    )
    Rules = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, verbose_name="Select rules for customer segmentation")
```

**forms.py**

```
class Segmentation_Form(ModelForm):
    Rules = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(), choices=models.segmentation_Rules.Segmentation_Rules_CHOICES)
```

Comment: I do so, selected choices are being stored correctly but the problem is when admin wants to edit a record in django-admin selected choices are not being shown.

Answer (score 1):

I am using this and its working fine

```
Rules = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=mychoices, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
```

i think you don't need `()` at the send of `CheckboxSelectMultiple`

Comment: it is not giving any error but displaying choices in a drop down list instead of check boxes  to me .

Comment: That exact same code worked for me in the frontend form. I am not sure if something is being overridden in Admin side by Django. i will have a look

Comment: Thanks,I want this for django admin , so if you found something please posted here

Answer (score 1):

### Use Multiple Choices in Admin with CharField Model

It stores the choices seperated by comma.

`models.py` and `admin.py` as they are

**forms.py**

```
from my_project.model import segmentation_Rules 

class Segmentation_Form(ModelForm):
      Rules = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, choices=segmentation_Rules.Segmentation_Rules_CHOICES, required=False)

      def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
          super(Segmentation_Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
          if kwargs.get('instance'):
              self.initial['Rules'] = eval(self.initial['Rules'])
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do that. You need to use the [MultipleChoiceField](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#multiplechoicefield) field with a [CheckboxSelectMultiple](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple) widget to do that. I think you are doing it right but maybe you forgot `()` in widgets?

```
class Segmentation_Form(forms.Form):
    Rules = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices= Segmentation_Rules_CHOICES, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())

    def clean_Rules(self):
        if len(self.cleaned_data['Rules']) > 3:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Select no more than 3.')
        return self.cleaned_data['Rules']
```

I have thrown in a validation method. Where you can have a limit on number of choices selected.

Comment: No it doesn't work for me , I have define choices in my models not in forms , is this the reason ??

Comment: no even i defined CHOICES in my models only. but forms need to be aware of this. since the widget works based on that.