# Change a MultipleChoiceField to only be able to select one choice at a time

Tags: python, django

so I am currently working on a program in Django that uses MultipleChoiceFields, I only want to be able to select one choice at a time within the bounds of my code. How exactly would I be able to change my MultipleChoice field to accomplish this goal, and what attributes would I need to add?

I have tried looking into documentation as well as some questions here as well for how one could modify the MultipleChoiceField function as seen here:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multiplechoicefield-django-forms/

[https://groups.google.com/g/django-users/c/faCorI1i8VE?pli=1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5747188/django-form-multiple-choice)

[Show multiple choices to admin in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14597937/show-multiple-choices-to-admin-in-django/14598061#14598061)

But I have found no attributes to help me limit the size of the answers one could pick out to just one answer, or the answers are unrelated to the problem I am seeking to solve.

Here is my code as well which also has the MultipleChoiceFields that I am trying to have select only one option:

```
class ArdvarkForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Course
    fields = ('is_done',)

    score_visual = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
    score_kinestetic = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
    score_auditory = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput())
    question1options = (('1', 'Read the instructions.'), ('2', 'Use the diagrams that explain the various stages, moves and strategies in the game.'), ('3', 'Watch others play the game before joining in.'), ('4', 'Listen to somebody explaining it and ask questions.'))
    question2options = (('1', 'Applying my knowledge in real situations.'), ('2', 'Applying my knowledge in real situations.'), ('3', 'Using words well in written communications'), ('4', 'Working with designs, maps or charts.'))
    question3options = (('1', 'Applying my knowledge in real situations.'), ('2', 'Communicating with others through discussion.'), ('3', 'Using words well in written communications.'), ('4', 'Working with designs, maps or charts.'))
    question4options = (('1', 'Read books, articles and handouts.'), ('2', 'Like to talk things through or talk things out.'), ('3', 'See patterns in things.'), ('4', 'Use examples and applications.'))
    question5options = (('1', 'Have a detailed discussion with my doctor'), ('2', 'To view a video of the property'), ('3', 'A discussion with the owner.'), ('4', 'A plan showing the rooms and a map of the area.'))
    question6options = (('1', 'A printed description of the rooms and features.'), ('2', 'To view a video of the property.'), ('3', 'A discussion with the owner.'), ('4', 'A plan showing the rooms and a map of the area.'))
    question7options = (('1', 'Podcasts and videos where I can listen to experts.'), ('2', 'Interesting design and visual features.'), ('3', 'Videos showing how to do things.'), ('4', 'Detailed articles.'))
    question8options = (('1', 'Talk with people who know about the program.'), ('2', 'Read the written instructions that came with the program.'), ('3', 'Follow the diagrams in a book.'), ('4', 'Start using it and learn by trial and error.'))
    question9options = (('1', 'Rely on paper maps or GPS maps.'), ('2', 'Head in the general direction to see if I can find my desination without instructions.'), ('3', 'Rely on verbal instructions from GPS or from someone traveling with me.'), ('4', 'Like to read instructions from GPS or instructions that have been written.'))
    question10options = (('1', 'An oppurtunity to discuss the project.'), ('2', 'Examples where the project has been used successfully.'), ('3', 'A written report describing the main features of the project.'), ('4', 'Diagrams to show the project stages with charts of benefits and costs.'))
    question11options = (('1', 'Use a map and see where the places are.'), ('2', 'Talk with the person who planned the tour or others who are going on the tour.'), ('3', 'Read about the tour on the itinerary.'), ('4', 'Look at details about the highlights and activities on the tour.'))
    question12options = (('1', 'Question and answer, talk, group discussion, or guest speakers.'), ('2', 'Diagrams, charts, maps or graphs.'), ('3', 'Handouts, books, or readings.'), ('4', 'Demonstrations, models or practical sessions.'))
    question13options = (('1', 'Reading the words'), ('2', 'Seeing the diagrams'), ('3', 'Listening.'), ('4', 'Watching the actions.'))
    question14options = (('1', 'Consider examples of each option using my financial information.'), ('2', 'Use graphs showing different options for different time periods.'), ('3', 'Read a print brochure that describes the options in detail.'), ('4', 'Talk with an expert about the options.'))
    question15options = (('1', 'Study diagrams showing each stage of the assembly.'), ('2', 'Read the instructions that came with the table.'), ('3', 'Ask for advice from someone who assembles furniture.'), ('4', 'Watch a video of a person assembling a similar table.'))
    question16options = (('1', 'Ask questions and talk about the camera and its features.'), ('2', 'Use diagrams showing the camera and what each part does.'), ('3', 'Use examples of good and poor photos showing how to improve them.'), ('4', 'Use the written instructions about what to do.'))

    question1 = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=question1options, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(), required=True, label='I want to learn how to play a new board game or card game. I would:')
    question2 = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=question2options, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(), label='I am having trouble assembling a wooden table that came in parts (kitset). I would:')
    question3 = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=question3options, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(), label='When learning from the Internet I like:')
    question4 = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=question4options, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(), label='I prefer a presenter or a teacher who uses:')
    question5 = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=question5options, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(), label='I want to find out more about a tour that I am going on. I would:')
    question6 = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=question6options, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(), label='I want to save more money and to decide between a range of options. I would:')
    question7 = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=question7options, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(), label='I want to learn how to take better photos. I would:')
    question8 = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=question8options, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(), label='A website has a video showing how to make a special graph or chart. There is a person speaking, some lists and words describing what to do and some diagrams. I would learn most from:')
    question9 = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=question9options, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(), label='I have been advised by the doctor that I have a medical problem and I have some questions about it. I would:')
    question10 = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=question10options, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(), label='I want to learn about a new project. I would ask for:')
    question11 = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=question11options,  widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(), label='I have finished a competition or test and I would like some feedback:')
    question12 = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=question12options, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(), label='When finding my way, I:')
    question13 = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=question13options, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(), label='I want to learn to do something new on a computer. I would:')
    question14 = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=question14options, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(), label='When choosing a career or area of study, these are important for me:')
    question15 = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=question15options, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(), label='When I am learning I:')
    question16 = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=question16options, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(), label='I want to find out about a house or an apartment. Before visiting it I would want:')
    is_done = forms.BooleanField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(),required=True, initial=False)
```

Any help on this matter would be most appretiated, thank you.

Comment: What prevents you from choosing a [`ChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/forms/fields/#choicefield) over a [`MulitpleChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/forms/fields/#multiplechoicefield)? A `ChoiceField` accepts only one selection by default.

Comment: As @Tarquinius noted, you should be using `ChoiceField`. `MultipleChoiceField` is specificially designed for exactly what it says...multiple choices. There's also some serious restructuring that needs to happen here for code legibility. You should share the source of your `Course` model, which should be handling most of the stuff you have in this form.